# How to override Similarity in a single field in Lucene?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, word-frequency

I am using **version 4.4** of Apache Lucene.

My system indexes a collection of documents into three different fields: the **title**, **description** and **author(s)** of the documents.

I want a document to get higher score the more frequency of a query term it has. However, when the term is part of the author field, I just want it to act as a "boolean"; this is, to add the same score if the term appears just once or more times. For example, if three authors of a document have a surname "Smith", just one match should be given.

For this, I have found the following code, which overrides the term frequency:

```
Similarity sim = new DefaultSimilarity() {
    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
        return freq == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }
};
searcher.setSimilarity(sim);
```

However, this overrides me it for the three fields. How can I manage to override the single author field?

Comment: I managed to solve it in the index process. I just remove duplicate names. Not a smart solution, but it's enough for me. If someone has a pleasent solution I would mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [PerFieldSimilarityWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/PerFieldSimilarityWrapper.html), like this:

```
public class MyCustomSimilarity extends PerFieldSimilarityWrapper {
    @Override
    public Similarity get(String fieldName) {
        if (fieldName.equals("author")) {
            return new CustomAuthorSimilarity();
        }
        else {
            return new DefaultSimilarity();
        }
    }
}
```